# How to fix a curl: (35) error when updating homebrew?

Tags: macos, ssl, curl, homebrew

I got this error while updating homebrew today on macOS Big Sur 11.3:

```
##O=#  #                                                                      
curl: (35) error:1400443E:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:tlsv1 alert inappropriate fallback
```

I update my homebrew packages with the following commands:

```sh
brew update
brew upgrade
brew cleanup
```

I repeated the above steps a second time and got the same error messages. I ran `brew doctor` and got the usual "your system is ready to brew" message.

While searching to see if anyone else had the issue, I found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/419152/cant-update-install-homebrew-packages-with-kaspersky-security-software-self-sig). Although the error in that person's issue isn't the same, I do have Kaspersky installed. I would like to know how to fix my issue or at least how to read the error message so that I can diagnose further. Thanks.

Comment: The error in apple #419152 _is_ the same: curl error 35 caused by OpenSSL error 1400443E. Everything else is just context. And yes TLS interception such as Kaspersky is a very likely cause of that error. It's not at all clear to me if this qualifies as a programming question, but I'll leave that to others.

Comment: Try disabling Kaspersky's Web Threat Protection (see [here](https://support.kaspersky.com/KESMac/11.1_adminguide/en-US/58556.htm)), then try doing the `update` & `upgrade`, then re-enable protection. If that solves it, I'd recommend giving that as an answer to the Ask Different question you found and then closing this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error today, and I read your messsage and the comments.
I have disabled Kaspersky protection and re-run `brew upgrade`
It worked with Kaspersky protection disabled.
I actually don't know how do it with Kaspersky protection enabled, but I have to search how to add this exception.

Comment: I don't know what Kaspersky had to do with this issue, but your strategy worked for me.